# I am trying to solve the following problem using python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code that finds the advanced stage uncertainty of a process given some variables, however my code isn't running properly and I could use some help. This is the problem I'm trying to solve:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I wrote the following code:

```
from scipy.stats import t
from sympy import diff, Symbol
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
'''exp = input('Enter the expression to find the propagation of error: ')
var = input('Enter the variables containing uncertainty seperated by spaces: ').split()
rss = [float(v) for v in input('Enter the variables RSS as a value seperated by spaces (if its in %, multiply by mean): ').split()]
num=[float(v) for v in input('Enter the number of measurements of each variable seperated by spaces: ').split()]
values=[float(v) for v in input('Enter the mean of each variable seperated by spaces: ').split()]
std=[float(v) for v in input('Enter the standard deviation of each variable seperated by spaces: ').split()]'''
exp = 'p/(54.7*t)'
var = ['p','t']
rss = [22.5391,0.6]
num=[20,10]
values=[2253.91,560.4]
std=[167.21,3]
for i,j in zip(var, values):
    a=exp.replace(i, str(j))
    print(a)
x=eval(a)
print(x)
b=[]
s=[]
sv=[]
for i in range(len(rss)):
    temp=rss[i]/2
    b.append(temp)
for i in range(len(var)):
    sp=std[i]/((num[i])**0.5)
    temp=num[i] -1
    s.append(sp)
    sv.append(temp)
symb = {x:Symbol(x, real = True) for x in var}  
val_table = {symb[x]:v for x, v in zip(var, values)}
symb = {x:Symbol(x, real = True) for x in var}  
val_table = {symb[x]:v for x, v in zip(var, values)}
func = parse_expr(exp, symb)  
derivatives = [diff(func, symb[x]) for x in var]
print(derivatives)  
error_s = (sum((u)*d.evalf(subs=val_table)**2 for u, d in zip(s, derivatives)))**0.5
error_b = (sum((u)*d.evalf(subs=val_table)**2 for u, d in zip(b, derivatives)))**0.5
print(error_s)
print(error_b)
vsk=[]
vbk=[]
for i in range(len(s)):
    v=((s[i])**4)/sv[i]
    vsk.append(v)
    s[i]=s[i]**2
for i in range(len(b)):
    b[i]=b[i]**2
sx=(sum(s))**0.5
print('the random uncertainty is: ',sx)
bx=(sum(b))**0.5
print('The systematic uncertainty is: ',bx)
cux=round((((sx)**2)+((bx)**2))**0.5,2)
print('The combined standard uncertainty is: ',cux)
den1=sum(vsk)
den2=sum(vbk)
v=round((((cux**2)**2)/(den1+den2)),0)
print('The degrees of freedom is: ',v)
tdist=t.ppf(1-((1-(95/100))/2), v)  
ecu=tdist*cux
print('The best estimate is:+/-',ecu)
```

I am getting 80 as a final answer instead of 0.0026 and I am unable to evaluate x; I think my mistake is with the derivative, I hope someone can help. Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a number of little errors. I recommend some longer variable names in the future to make it easier for someone else to figure out what they are referring to, especially if you are looking for assistance. Please also try to follow the [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations) especially when it concerns whitespace around operators, it will really make your code more readable.

In terms of your implementation, you had 3 problems.

## First Issue (Parentheses)

Your parentheses were incorrect around your error_s and error_b calculations.

```py
(sum((u)*d.evalf(subs=val_table)**2 for u, d in zip(s, derivatives)))**0.5
#      ^ This One
```

should have been

```py
(sum((u*d.evalf(subs=val_table))**2 for u, d in zip(s, derivatives)))**0.5
#                              ^ Should've been here
```

For this reason you were only squaring the value from the evaluated derivative not the whole product.

Here are the correct lines for your implementation:

```py
error_s = (sum((u * d.evalf(subs=val_table)) ** 2 for u, d in zip(s, derivatives))) ** 0.5
error_b = (sum((u * d.evalf(subs=val_table)) ** 2 for u, d in zip(b, derivatives))) ** 0.5
```

## Second Issue (Logic Error)

Second, you were not calculating the estimate correctly.
You were using `sx` and `sb` to build `cux` instead of using your `error_s` and `error_b` values you calculated earlier. I don't know if this is because your `error_` variables contained incorrect information so this was a second attempt, but replacing it with your corrected `error_` variables yields the expected result.

```py
ecu = t_dist * ((error_s ** 2 + error_b ** 2) ** 0.5)
```

Assuming you've updated the `error_s` and `error_b` lines to match those above, you can replace the `ecu` assignment in your program and your program will produce the expected results without any further modification.

## Third Issue (Evaluating X)

Your code produced an error.

```py
for i, j in zip(var, values):
    a = exp.replace(i, str(j))
x = eval(a)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 20, in <module>
    x = eval(a)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'p' is not defined
```

This is because your replacement did not replace both variables correctly. Each time you replace you store the updated string in a, but refer back to exp instead of your updated string a. So you still had one variable left unreplaced.

You should replace this code with something like:

```py
# Replace variables with values
filled_expr = exp
for i, j in zip(var, values):
    filled_expr = filled_expr.replace(i, str(j))

# Evaluate expression
x = eval(filled_expr)
```

Alternatively you can use `evalf` from `sympy` on your `func` directly since you already have it setup from when you calculate the derivatives.

```py
x = func.evalf(subs=val_table)
```

## Modified Implementation

In attempting to understand the problem, and your implementation, I ended up making several modifications to simplify the expressions where possible. I tried to preserve as many of your variable names as possible. I also stripped away a number of operations that did not directly make progress towards the goal of calculating the total uncertainty as this was the area at issue in your question. Please reintroduce these computations if they were important to some other requirement than those listed in your question.

My complete modified implementation is below:

```py
from scipy.stats import t
from sympy import diff, Symbol
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

exp = 'p/(54.7*t)'
var = ['p', 't']
rss = [22.5391, 0.6]
num = [20, 10]
values = [2253.91, 560.4]
std = [167.21, 3]

b = [b1 / 2 for b1 in rss]

s = []
sv = []
for s1, n1 in zip(std, num):
    sp = s1 / (n1 ** 0.5)
    s.append(sp)
    sv.append(n1 - 1)

symbols = {x: Symbol(x, real=True) for x in var}
val_table = {sy: v for sy, v in zip(symbols.values(), values)}

# Calculate Derivatives
func = parse_expr(exp, symbols)
derivatives = [diff(func, sy) for sy in symbols.values()]
evaluated_derivatives = [d.evalf(subs=val_table) for d in derivatives]

# Estimate Density Uncertainties
error_s, error_b = [(sum((u * ed) ** 2 for u, ed in zip(l, evaluated_derivatives))) ** 0.5 for l in [s, b]]

# Find Equivalent #DoF
v_num = (sum((u * ed) ** 2 for u, ed in zip(s + b, evaluated_derivatives * 2))) ** 2
v_denom = sum(sum(((u * ed) ** 4) / v for u, ed, v in zip(l, evaluated_derivatives, sv)) for l in [s, b])
v = float(v_num / v_denom)
print(f'The degrees of freedom is: {v:.0f}')

# Total Uncertainty
t_dist = t.ppf(1 - ((1 - (95 / 100)) / 2), v)
ecu = t_dist * ((error_s ** 2 + error_b ** 2) ** 0.5)

# Evaluate Expression With Value Replacement
x = func.evalf(subs=val_table)
print(f'The best estimate is: {x:.3f}+/-{ecu:.4f}')
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much!!!!!!How can I evaluate x to print it in the last line 
print('The best estimate is:',x,'+/-', ecu)

Comment: You don't have anything called 'x' in your program other than your comprehension variable when you build the symbols dict. I assume the x you're referring to is the 0.074 in the above image, however, I don't see any equations for calculating that value, am I missing it somewhere in your question?

Comment: x is the mean, we can call it mu; we can get it by replacing the values of the variables in exp by the rss value. I tried to do the following but it didnt work:

for i,j in zip(var, values):
    a=exp.replace(i, str(j))
    print(a)
x=eval(a)

Comment: Right. I removed that since it caused an error for me since your replacement didn't handle both variables correctly. Thank you for the clarification. I've updated my solution to include the calculation of 'x'.